# average correlation of z dim of an x,y rolling window in numpy

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, scipy, correlation

I would like to write some code that helps me assess how good some fits are. I have a 3D matrix. The z dimension is a fit to some data at point i, j of the matrix. I would like to assess if this fit is good by comparing the fit at point i, j to the fits of its nearest neighbours (in the x,y dimension). If the fits of the neighbours are similar to the fit at that point then I would like to keep the fit. I hope that makes sense.

What that boils down to is: is there a good way to have a rolling window across the x,y dimension that calculates the Pearson's r in the z dim of the window central point to all the other points in the window and takes the mean (or even the number of points with r greater than some constant).

I can only think how to do this in a very long handed inefficient way currently. For some background information, I am fitting these data with a fourier series. Ultimately I want to use this technique to assess the minimum number of waves to use in the fourier fits at each point.

Thanks in advance
Niall

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution but its not very efficient. (by the way, was another dimension of data I didn't bother telling you about in the question. Has anyone got any suggestions of more efficient ways to do this?

Thanks again

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
from bottleneck import nanmean

def calc_corr_of_neighbours(data, win_shape):
    rs = np.empty(data.shape[1:])
    thisrs = np.empty(win_shape)
    win_data = np.empty(win_shape)
    dA = int(win_shape[0]/2)
    dB = int(win_shape[1]/2)
    maxA = data.shape[2]
    maxB = data.shape[3]

    for i in np.ndindex(rs.shape):
        stA = max(i[1]-dA, 0)
        endA = min(i[1]+dA, maxA)
        stB = max(i[2]-dB, 0)
        endB = min(i[2]+dB, maxB)

        win_data = data[:, i[0], stA:endA, stB:endB]

        thisrs.fill(np.NaN)
        for j in np.ndindex(win_data.shape[1:]):
            thisrs[j] = pearsonr(data[:, i[0], i[1], i[2]], win_data[:, j[0], j[1]])[0]

        rs[i] = nanmean(thisrs)

    return rs
```